# Is the Ubuntu policy manual out of date?

Tags: development, documentation, policy

I just started reading the [Ubuntu Architecture wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuArchitecture) which outlines the overall architecture of Ubuntu. Got to the section that discusses the Ubuntu Policy Manual and that it is derived from the Debian Policy Manual.

I noticed that at the bottom of the [Ubuntu Policy Manual](http://people.canonical.com/~cjwatson/ubuntu-policy/policy.html/) that the document has not been changed since 2009-06-19. I also noticed the [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) was last updated on 2011-04-07.

Could be that no changes were necessary, but given the **tight symbiosis between Ubuntu and Debian** I would expect a more recent change date for the Ubuntu Policy Manual.

It could be that there just was no reason to update the document in over two years, but I am looking to better understand why?

Answer (score 2):

When I go to the page in your link I see this at the bottom of the page

> UbuntuArchitecture (last edited 2010-06-05 19:40:17 by

So, the answer is - not so out of date as it used to be.

Comment: That's still over a year old.

Comment: Or maybe the question should be, "When was the Ubuntu Policy Manual last reviewed?"